# localStorage is not defined - Next.js

Tags: local-storage, next.js, tailwind-css

I just set up a function to toggle the dark mode while using Tailwind CSS. This error popped up out of nowhere since it was working fine like 5 minutes ago. I haven't changed any of the code but all of sudden, this error popped.

I'm using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. Not much of a code expert, just studying and trying stuff out. Here's the function at which I use localStorage:

```
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.theme);
  const colorTheme = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
  useEffect(() => {
    const root = window.document.documentElement;

    root.classList.remove(colorTheme);
    root.classList.add(theme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
  }, [theme, colorTheme]);

  return [colorTheme, setTheme];
}
```

Would love for some light in here. This is just strange to me as it was working

Answer (score 0):

This is because nextjs runs on both the server and client side. On the server side, you cannot access the window object that owns localStorage, it only appears when the component is mounted in the dom. Thus, you can move your localStorage to the useEffect hook like this

```
const [theme, setTheme] = useState();

useEffect (() => {
  
     setTheme(localStorage.theme)
    
}, []);
```

Comment: I've since then removed the localStorage.theme from the useState, leaving it to a default of dark. But now the localStorage isn't working at all. When changing routes, the browser don't remember which theme was on and it goes back to the default. 

```export default function DarkModeToggle() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark');
  const colorTheme = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
  useEffect(() => {
    const root = window.document.documentElement;```

The code below this snippet remains the same.

Comment: Don't remove localStorage. Just move it to the useEffect hook. It should work. It will be good if you create a minimal working code snippet. I will try to help you

Comment: Not sure if it's working properly but I've tried to upload to a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-haslett-f31wk

Comment: Sorry but i cant to run your codesandbox example,there are terminal errors